# How to display images in html with javascript?

Tags: javascript, image

I want to display images in html using javascript .

```
 <html>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var path_img = "/Upload/Images/123.png";
});
</script>
 <img src="<%Request[path_img].val(); %>" class="img-thumbnail" />
</body>
</html>
```

It's seem not working .

Comment: That's not JavaScript.

Comment: using html of

<img class="img-thumbnail" />

In the script you can just do $(".img-thumbnail").attr("src", path_img);

( this assumes you're using jquery )

If you want to do multiple images you can use a for loop in the javascript and insert img tags into the body with the src for each image.

Comment: Well, It's done, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't javascript. Try the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var path_img = "/Upload/Images/123.png";
            $('#img1')[0].src = path_img;
});
</script>
<img id="img1" class="img-thumbnail" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Dear user1823, I want to show images from script `path_image` . How can i do it ?

Comment: In case , `<img src="source_pictute" />` , I know, but i want to show it from script `path_image`.thank

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using jQuery. If yes, you could simply tag the element with a ID or class and handle via jQuery, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      var path_img = "/Upload/Images/123.png";
      $('.my_images').attr("src", path_img);
   });
</script>

<img class="my_images" class="img-thumbnail" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
   <script>
     $(function() {
       $("#path_img").attr("src","/Upload/Images/123.png");
     });
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <img id="path_img" class="img-thumbnail" />
 </body>
</html>
```